# I've found the remains of a doomsday-cult mass suicide. Can I do anything with their Poisoned Wine?

Tags: fallout-4

Just south of Boston Common, I found the remains of the Boylston Social Club, hangout for Boston's wealthy and powerful. It looks like, when the bombs hit, they raised one last toast and drank themselves to death with Poisoned Wine, a half a dozen bottles of which were still left lying around the club, 200 years later, for me to, well, procure.

The stat-line in the pip boy doesn't make this Poisoned Wine seem like it's anything different from regular Wine - it has an identical statistical effect - but it does sell to a vendor for substantially more.

That's boring though. Is there anything more interesting I can do with the Poisoned Wine? If I plant it on someone, will they drink it and die? Or am I overthinking some quick caps?

Comment: Have you tried drinking it yet?

Comment: You can plant live mines and it'll blow people up, so why not poisoned wine and poison people?

Comment: @Paralytic Yeah. At least on my own character, it has no effect above and beyond that of, just, y'know, Wine.

Comment: Is it still a doomsday cult if doomsday actually arrives?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately according to the Fallout Wiki it says:

> Despite the name, the only adverse affects of drinking it is a penalty
>   to Intelligence.

Reference:

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Poisoned_wine

Now, I personally haven't tried this myself, but you could potentially use this in conjunction with the [Junk Jet](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Junk_Jet). Who said launching poison wine followed by a teddy bear can't be fun? Even though the wiki says:

> All ammunition has the same damage, as even soft teddy bears do the
>   same damage as items that would normally have deadly effects, like
>   deathclaw hands.

I wouldn't see why you couldn't at least make some use out of it other than losing a bit of intelligence!

Comment: Its a Junk Jet in fallout 4

Comment: So the people had 1 INT and then drank it to lose that last point and their brains died.